# Cassandra - cqlsh returns inconsistent results even if CONSISTENCY LEVEL set to ALL or QUORUM

Tags: count, cassandra, consistency, eventual-consistency

I have a Cassandra cluster with 4 nodes. 
I have a keyspace with replication factor  3.

Here are the sample cqlsh results I get when I do "select count(*) on a particular table. The results are consistently different even if consistency level is set as ALL or QUORUM.

---

cqlsh:test> CONSISTENCY all

Consistency level set to ALL.

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article;

### count

28620
(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article;

### count

28703
(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article;

### count

28046
(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> CONSISTENCY QUORUM

Consistency level set to QUORUM.

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article;

### count

28612
(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article;

### count

28122
(1 rows)

cqlsh:test>

---

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug that may have been fixed in release 2.1.6.

See this ticket:

[CASSANDRA-8940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8940)

Are you using an earlier release than 2.1.6?

Comment: Thanks Jim. This is useful. Let me upgrade to 2.1.6 and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually I think that may be cqlsh way of work.
From http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table LIMIT 50000;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table LIMIT 200000;
```

The output of these statements if you had 105,291 rows in the database would be: 50000, and 105,291. The cqlsh shell has a default row limit of 10,000. The Cassandra server and native protocol do not limit the number of rows that can be returned, although a timeout stops running queries to protect against running malformed queries that would cause system instability.

Try cqlsh:test> select count(*) from article LIMIT 200000; or another large value

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had actually tried this as well. Here is what I got -    cqlsh:owlin> select count(*) from article limit 1000000;

 count
-------
 27778

(1 rows)
cqlsh:owlin> select count(*) from article limit 1000000;

 count
-------
 28812

(1 rows)

Comment: From my experience I do not trust cqlsh. If you want to be sure, query all rows via some driver and count it, then compare with this results. There are two options: 1. cqlsh lies 2. there is something about clqsh we don't know :) As Jim Meyer posted, this bug would explain much